# The property 'someProp' does not exist on value of type 'object' in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a JSON object returned to me from an $.ajax call.  I get my object from my response like so:

```
var parsedJSON = $.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText);
```

The object itself that gets passed from the server has a ResponseStatus property, and in that ResponseStatus property, there is an ErrorCode and Message.  I thought I'd just be able to do this:

```
var r = parsedJSON.ResponseStatus;
```

But I get the error: `The property 'ResponseStatus' does not exist on value of type 'object'`

Because this is typescript, when I try to save the file and then have VS create my Javascript, it won't.

Am I missing something super obvious here?  I can create an interface and cast the object to the interface like this:

```
var parsedJSON: IHttpResponseStatus = <IHttpResponseStatus> $.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText);
var r = parsedJSON.ResponseStatus;
```

But this seems like overkill to get a property, and pretty wrong.  Thanks in advance.

Edit: Oh nevermind, you can use array notation and TS doesn't care.  Whoops!

Comment: If you update to the latest jquery.d.ts from definitely typed you will no longer need to do casting since my pull request got merged https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/pull/554

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's becuase jquery.d.ts defines parseJSON as:

```
parseJSON(json: string): Object;
```

It should be any. You can cast the result yourself to avoid creating an interface

```
var parsedJSON = <any> $.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText);
var r = parsedJSON.ResponseStatus;
```

or:

```
var parsedJSON:any = $.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText);
var r = parsedJSON.ResponseStatus;
```

I've sent a pull request as well : https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/pull/554